# Java Swing cardlayout when card loaded

Tags: java, swing, indexing, cardlayout

I am using Java CardLayout to switch between cards and JPanel. When activity starts in android I can use onLoad, or similar to check if the activity is now open. What is the equivalent to this in swing? How can I know if the JPanel (Card) is now in front?

```
public class FirstScreen extends JPanel 
{
//am I visible now?
}
```

Comment: A Panel should go inside a Frame. You mean being visible into the Frame or the frame itself to be visible in the OS desktop?

Comment: The JPanel is inside frame in other class, when I open it I use show function. When the FirstScreen is shown I need to know about this in itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `windowActivated()` in a `WindowListener` or `WindowAdapter`, as shown in *How to Write Window Listeners* and this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2889692/230513). See also [*How to Write a Component Listener*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html).

Addendum: To receive notification that a particular card was selected, use a `PropertyChangeEvent`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523401/230513), or an `AncestorEvent`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17993449/230513).

Comment: @mKorbel: good idea; there's an `AncestorListener` example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17993449/230513).